# Use XAML-Builds with TFS 2018 Update 2

Tags: tfs, build, xamlbuild

We installed the newest TFS Server (TFS 2018 Update 2) which should run xaml builds.
After the update, we started our agent, but our xaml-controller is still offline and I don't know how I start this again..

Any ideas what we can do?

Comment: Did you get any related error info about the offline xaml build controller in Team Foundation Server administration console?

Comment: NO i didn't find anything in the log and in the console, there is no menu for the xaml build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @PatrickLu-MSFT!! through your help, we found a workaround.
Now we use one server for the Source Control etc. (TFS 2018) and another server only for the xaml-app-controller with TFS 2015. 
So we can build our projects, and have time to create new build definitions.

Answer (score 5):

> Yes, you can now upgrade to TFS 2018 Update 2 and continue to connect
>   your XAML controllers and run XAML builds. When we removed support for
>   XAML build in TFS 2018 RTW and Update 1, some of you could not upgrade
>   due to having legacy XAML builds, and we want to unblock you. Although
>   TFS 2018 Update 2 supports XAML builds for your legacy builds, XAML
>   build is **deprecated and there will be no further investment**, so we
>   highly recommend converting to a newer build definition format. See
>   the [Evolving TFS/Team Services build automation capabilities](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/05/30/evolving-tfsteam-services-build-automation-capabilities/) blog
>   for more information about XAML build deprecation.

When you upgrade to TFS 2018 Update 2:

- If you have any XAML build data in your team project collection,
  you'll get a warning about the deprecation of XAML build features.
- You will need to use VS or Team Explorer 2017 to edit XAML build
  definitions or to queue new XAML builds.
- If you need to create new XAML build agents, you’ll need to install
  them using the TFS 2015 build agent installer.

XAML Build Controller/Agent info is now under **Additional Tools and Components > XAML Build Configuration** in the TFS Administration Console. Make sure your build services on the same server as your application tier. **You possibly didn't re-configure your XAML build services after the upgrade.** Try this and then check again.

Comment: in the team foundation server adminstration console the "XAML Build Configuration" is missing in the menu...

Comment: @D.Nehl Sorry about this, I got the same result as you. There is no "XAML Build Configuration" menu in adminstration console just like TFS 2018 unlike TFS2017(which you could still use XAML) This is wired and there is not any official document tell us how to continue to connect XAML controllers and run XAML builds on TFS2018 update2 for now. Suggest you submit this issue to [DeveloperCommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/22/index.html) TFS developer and PM will kindly review it and give a solution to you.

Comment: @D.Nehl You can install the XAML build controller from a previous version of TFS. The only way this would be a problem is if you had your XAML build running on your application tier, which is an incredibly bad idea anyway.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT we had the same issue upgrading to TFS 2018 Update 2. There is no XAML Build Configuration interface in the new TFS Console. Is there another way to control the XAML build controller without that UI? I submitted an issue here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/256956/after-upgrading-to-tfs-2018-update-2-the-xaml-buil.html

Comment: FYI - If anyone is upgrading from TFS 2013->2018 and you can use your old TFS 2013 build service, but you'll need to delete / recreate your controllers and agents